# Kinect SDK 1.0 namespaces

Tags: kinect

I made a little program using my XBOX 360 kinect with the Kinect SDK beta 2.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Today I installed the released commercial SDK 1.0 and tried to rebuild my solution but it failed.

I changed the referenced dll inside my code from Microsoft.Research.Kinect to Microsoft.Kinect.

But it seems that all the namespaces I used with the beta SDK do not exist anymore in the release and have been replaced by something else.

Is there any detailed api documentation somewhere on what's new? I couldn't find any on MSDN...

Comment: Ok, I found it... 

I have to say it's not trivial.

Many things have indeed been changed between the beta 2 and the 1.0.

More info in this 
[post.](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-code-migration-from-beta2-to-v1-0-managed/)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll accept my own answer which is the comment in the question:

Many things have indeed been changed between the beta 2 and the 1.0.

More info in this post:

http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-code-migration-from-beta2-to-v1-0-managed/

Hope it will help.